# Need to access HttpOnly cookie in HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, httponly, cookiecontainer

I am trying to get automatically login into a website using POST method and everything seem to work fine except that my HttPWebResponse method conveniently skips a cookie that is marked as HttpOnly. Is there any way I can read it.

```
 public CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();
```

down in the code I have

```
request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
```

I have read that when using CookieContainer I should not worry about reading the HttpOnly cookies as they are handled atomically. But apparently this is not the case. Using fiddler I do see that I get the 4 cookies but response.Cookies size if 3 and using the same code gets the next request rejected. Please help!!

Full code is as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest request = CreateRequest(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
return  DecodeResponse(response);
```

DecodeResponse works as follows

```
foreach (System.Net.Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
     Console.WriteLine(cookie.HttpOnly);

     _cookies.Add(new Uri(response.ResponseUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), cookie);
```

}

Comment: Can you show your full code with the `HttpWebResponse`

Answer (score 0):

> Cookie `HttpOnly` Determines whether a page script or other active
>   content can access this cookie.

The code below returns true if the cookie has the `HttpOnly` attribute and cannot be accessed through a client-side script; otherwise, false.

```
    var _cookies = new CookieContainer();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://yourURL.com");
    request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
        Console.WriteLine(cook.HttpOnly);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It prints 3 false. Where in reality it should print 3 false and 1 true. Somehow the code does not see the HTTPOnly cookie. I have added this suggestion in my sample code.